# Scala - convert Array[String] to Array[Double]

Tags: arrays, scala, functional-programming

I am a newbie to functional programming language and I am learning it in Scala for a University project.

This may seem simple, but I am unable to find enough help online for this or a straightforward way of doing this - how can I convert an Array[String] to Array[Double]? I have a CSV file which, when read into the REPL is interpreted as String values (each line of the file has a mix of integer and string values) which would return a type Array[String]. I want to encode the string values with a double/int values to return Array[Double] in order to make the array homogeneous. Is there a straightforward way of doing this? Any guidance will be much appreciated.

What I have done until now is:

```
def retrieveExamplesFromFile(fileName : String) : Array[Array[String]] = {
  val items = for {
    line <- Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines()
    entries = line.split(",")
    } yield entries

  return items.toArray
}
```

The format of each line (returned as String[]) is so:

```
[[1.0, 2.0, item1], [5, 8.9, item2],....]
```

And to convert each line in the CSV file into double array, I only have a psuedo definition drafted so:

```
def generateNumbersForStringValues(values : Array[String]) : Array[Double] = {
val line = for(item <- values)
{
    //correct way?
    item.replace("item1", "1.0")
    item.replace("item2", "1.0")    
} 
return //unable to typecast/convert
}
```

Any ideas are welcome. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You probably want to use `map` along with `toDouble`:

```
values.map(x => x.toDouble)
```

Or more concisely:

```
values.map(_.toDouble)
```

And for the fallback for non-double strings, you might consider using the `Try` monad (in `scala.util`):

```
values.map(x => Try(x.toDouble).getOrElse(1.0))
```

If you know what each line will look like, you could also do pattern matching:

```
values map { 
    case Array(a, b, c) => Array(a.toDouble, b.toDouble, 1.0)
}
```

Comment: The getOrElse statement or pattern matching works the best for me. However, I wanted to know if I can add counter to this rather than returning just 1.0 all the time? I have heard of Range(n1, n2) but that is not what I am looking for, I am looking for a counter because I want item1 and item2 to have different (maybe consecutive) numbers. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure -- you can put whatever logic you want in the `getOrElse` clause.  For example, you could make an iterator `val fallbackIterator = Iterator.from(0)`, and then use `getOrElse(fallbackIterator.next)`, so that each successive call to `getOrElse` will increment the fallback value.

Comment: I was looking for that Try monad: did not know in scala.util.  v pretty answer here.

Answer (score 3):

You mean to convert all strings to double with a fallback to 1.0 for all inconvertible strings? That would be:

```
val x = Array(
  Array("1.0", "2.0", "item1"),
  Array("5", "8.9", "item2"))

x.map( _.map { y =>
  try {
    y.toDouble
  } catch {
    case _: NumberFormatException => 1.0
  }
})
```

Comment: better to catch the `java.lang.NumberFormatException` to avoid the compiler warning

Comment: @dhg and more importantly: to avoid catching fatal exceptions like OOM and internal VM errors.

Comment: isn't it better to use monad `Try`?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @DaunnC's comment, you can use the `Try` utility to do this and pattern match on the result so you can avoid calling `get` or wrapping your result in an `Option`:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def main = {
  val maybeDoubles = Array("5", "1.0", "8.5", "10.0", "item1", "item2")

  val convertDoubles = maybeDoubles.map { x =>
    Try(x.toDouble)
  }

  val convertedArray = convertDoubles.map {
    _ match {
      case Success(res) => res
      case Failure(f) => 1.0
   }
  }

  convertedArray
}
```

This allows you to pattern match on the result of `Try`, which is always either a `Success` or `Failure`, without having to call `get` or otherwise wrap your results.

Here is some more information on Try courtesy of Mauricio Linhares: https://mauricio.github.io/2014/02/17/scala-either-try-and-the-m-word.html

Comment: Copy/pasted your code into my main method and I get this O/P: Success(5.0)
Success(1.0)
Success(8.5)
Success(10.0)
Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "item1")
Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "item2")

Comment: Ah, that would be because it wasn't yielding the final map. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Scala 2.13` introduced [`String::toDoubleOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/StringOps.html#toDoubleOption:Option[Double]) which used within a `map` transformation, can be associated with `Option::getOrElse` to safely cast `String`s into `Double`s:

```
Array("5", "1.0", ".", "8.5", "int").map(_.toDoubleOption.getOrElse(1d))
// Array[Double] = Array(5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 8.5, 1.0)
```